# Resetting the camera far plane

Tags: camera, three.js

I'm trying to update make my camera far clip plane to sit on Vector3(0,0,0) no matter how close or far the camera gets, I've managed to find a way of updating the far clip plane dynamically but I can't get this plane to face my camera.

Thanks, C.

```js
var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
matrix.extractRotation(camera.matrix);

var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
direction.subVectors( new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0), camera.position );
direction.normalize();

var N = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
N.applyMatrix4(matrix);

var planePos = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);

var clipPlane = new THREE.Plane();
clipPlane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(N, planePos);
clipPlane.applyMatrix4(camera.matrixWorldInverse);

clipPlane = new THREE.Vector4(clipPlane.normal.x, clipPlane.normal.y, clipPlane.normal.z, clipPlane.constant);

var q = new THREE.Vector4();
var projectionMatrix = camera.projectionMatrix;

q.x = (sgn(clipPlane.x) + projectionMatrix.elements[8]) / projectionMatrix.elements[0];
q.y = (sgn(clipPlane.y) + projectionMatrix.elements[9]) / projectionMatrix.elements[5];
q.z = -1.0;
q.w = (1.0 + projectionMatrix.elements[10]) / camera.projectionMatrix.elements[14];

// Calculate the scaled plane vector
var c = new THREE.Vector4();
c = clipPlane.multiplyScalar(2000.0 ); //clipPlane.multiplyScalar(2.0 / clipPlane.dot(q)); /// clipPlane.dot(q)

// Replace the third row of the projection matrix
projectionMatrix.elements[2] = c.x;
projectionMatrix.elements[6] = c.y;
projectionMatrix.elements[10] = c.z + 1.0;
projectionMatrix.elements[14] = c.w;
```

Comment: Is the camera always looking at the origin? If so, try: `camera.far = camera.position.length(); camera.updateProjectionMatrix();`

Comment: elegant solution, perfectly solves my problem. thanks @WestLangley was really over thinking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reset the `far` plane parameter for a camera, you can use this pattern

```
camera.far = new_value;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

In your particular case, you can do this:

```
camera.far = camera.position.length();
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

three.js r.72